# Cannot construct instance of `{dataclass}, problem: Should never call `set()` on setterless property

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, jackson, deserialization, ktor

"authors" is my collection in MongoDB.

my schema

```
authors = [
{

name: "Author1",
books: [

{title:"Book1"},
{title:"Book2"}

]
}
]
```

I'm trying to append the books array by adding another book object (book3). Before that, I have to check whether there exists an object already in the author's name. So I have the findOneByAuthorname function.

My issue is that every time I try to call the findOneByAuthorname function. I get an error

```
  - Unhandled: POST - /v1/api/addBooks. Exception class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException:  Cannot construct instance of `com.sample.models.schema.Author`, problem: Should never call `set()` on setterless property ('books')
```

I'm using postman for the post request and passing a JSON object {title: "book3"}.

My code :

```
    @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
    data class Author ( val name: String , val books : MutableList<Bookitem>)
    @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
    data class Bookitem (val title :String)
    
    private var collection : CoroutineCollection<Author> = MongoConfig.getDatabase().getCollection("authors")
    
    suspend fun findOneByAuthorname(Name:String) : Author {
    collection.findOne(Author::name eq Name)
}
    suspend fun addBooks(Name:String,book:Bookitem) : Bookitem?{

    collection.findOneandUpdate(Author::name eq  Name, ,push(Author::books ,Bookitem(book)))
}
```

I have added the relevant details ( or that I feel are relevant here). Find function works if I disregard the books dataclass completely. If any more details is required, kindly mention in the comments and I'll add. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the variable type of `books: MutableList<Bookitem>` from **var** to **val**. Since objects are added this is the way to declare it.
Still, I'm not able to understand what the error message means.